# how to create native distributions (installers/packages) for all the supported systems with compose?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, desktop, compose-desktop

I created a desktop application project with Compose.

Now I ask how do I port this project to an exe application to share it?

I searched in several sources and did not find anything. I asked some and did not receive a response from them.

Comment: Have you read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you added the `TargetFormat.Msi` to the following block you should have a gradle tasks like `packageMsi` or `packagaReleaseMsi`. Further questions might be answered by this [Readme](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md).

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "your.package.MainKt"
        javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "AppName"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```